# Public flags are not applied to libraries (cmake)

Tags: c, cmake

With Cmake, I would like to apply some general flags to both executable and libraries.

Well, I thought I could use **target_compile_options** by using PUBLIC keyword. I tested on a small example with an executable and a static library, both having only one file (main.c & mylib.c), but that does not work as expected.

The root CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

# Add the library
add_subdirectory(mylib)

# Create the executable
add_executable(mytest main.c)

# Link the library
target_link_libraries(mytest mylib)

# Add public flags 
target_compile_options(mytest PUBLIC -Wall)
```

And the library's CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

add_library(mylib STATIC mylib.c)
```

The flag **-Wall** is applied only on the main.c and not on the library file (mylib.c):

```
[ 25%] Building C object mylib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/mylib.c.o
cd /patsux/Programmation/Repositories/test-cmake-public/build/mylib && /usr/lib/hardening-wrapper/bin/cc     -o CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/mylib.c.o   -c /patsux/Programmation/Repositories/test-cmake-public/mylib/mylib.c
[ 50%] Linking C static library libmylib.a
[ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/main.c.o
/usr/lib/hardening-wrapper/bin/cc    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/main.c.o   -c /patsux/Programmation/Repositories/test-cmake-public/main.c
```

Now, If flags are applied on the library instead of the executable, that work.

```
# Add public flags on the library
target_compile_options(mylib PUBLIC -Wall)
```

I get:

```
[ 25%] Building C object mylib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/mylib.c.o
cd /patsux/Programmation/Repositories/test-cmake-public/build/mylib &&        /usr/lib/hardening-wrapper/bin/cc    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/mylib.c.o   -c /patsux/Programmation/Repositories/test-cmake-public/mylib/mylib.c
[ 50%] Linking C static library libmylib.a

[ 75%] Building C object CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/main.c.o
/usr/lib/hardening-wrapper/bin/cc    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/mytest.dir/main.c.o   -c /patsux/Programmation/Repositories/test-cmake-public/main.c
[100%] Linking C executable mytest
```

That makes no sense to set general flags such as the type of target on a library.

How can I share general flags properly ? I know I can use **add_definitions()**. Is it the right way ?

I also tested:

```
set_target_properties(mytest PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -Wall)
```

But flags are not public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the flag like this in your root file:

```
add_compile_options(-Wall)
```

Or, if you were using a cmake version prior to 3.0:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")
```

Comment: Yes. Probably I will use **add_compile_options()** to apply flags on both C and C++ compilers.

Comment: I didn't know about add_compile_options(). You're right, it's a better option. I edit my answer